# WorkManager - Can WorkRequest maximum backoff time for retries be changed?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm using WorkManager to queue up OneTimeWorkRequests for file uploads. This of course requires network connectivity, and if the device does not have connectivity and the upload fails, it will retry as per my specified retry/backoff policy.

My question is simply:

**Can I change the maximum backoff time for the retry?**

The maximum backoff time is set to 5 hours by default and I would ideally like to reduce this, but I have not been able to find a way to do so.

See my code for enqueueing a work request below:

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest uploadRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadFileWorker.class)
                .setInputData(createInputDataForUri(file.getPath()))
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL,
                        OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_FILE_UPLOAD, ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, uploadRequest);
```

We can easily set the BackoffPolicy (linear/exponential) and backoffDelay with `.setBackoffCriteria()`, as well as add an initial delay to the request, but I see no way to customise the maximum backoff time for the retry. Is this by design, or am I just blind?